# When initializing a bool32_t object in C++, do we need to cast it or it automatically recognize it?

Tags: c++, casting

I want to know what is the correct way to initialize a `bool32_t` variable in C++

Does `bool32_t` do the casting internally when I declare my variable as

```
bool32_t blah = false;
```

or should I explicitely cast it.

```
blah = static_cast<bool32_t>(false);
```

I would prefer not having to cast it. If so, does this internal casting work for C++11 or even earlier versions? Does `bool32_t` belong to C++ std library?

Comment: Where does the `bool32_t` type come from? I can't find that in standard C++. If there is a `typedef` for that type, go take a look and see how the underlying type handles casting `true` and `false`.

Comment: That's what I did. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `bool32_t` does not belong to the C++ standard library as far as my knowledge goes. Apart from that, I see no point in it being part of the standard library, as a boolean only ever needs to store two possible values, 0 and 1, which represent false and true respectively. And that takes only 1 bit [Even though a boolean itself is usually 1 byte in size, though that may vary with implementation]. So a boolean type that has a size of 32 bytes seems of no apparent use to me.

So, I think you should be a bit more detailed with your question, provide more information about the `bool32_t` type, as it is impossible to help you without knowing what that type does or where it originates from

Comment: Note that in C++, `bool` must be at least one whole byte.

Comment: @hegel5000 I am aware of that. The minimum amount of size a variable can take is 1 byte, excluding bitsets and bit fields of course

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. This bool32_t was defined in the context of MPI and making generic the memory allocation for all the cases. The code I am working on is massive and I thought this was defined as the standard. But began to doubt it after reserching a good deal. I want to make sure it wasn't... I hope it help some other sould lost looking for this.

Answer (score 0):

> Does `bool32_t` belong to C++ std library?

No it does not. It's easy to confirm this by quickly searching from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=bool32_t), or Ctrl+F the latest [standard draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/n4830.pdf).

> I want to know what is the correct way to initialize a `bool32_t`
>   variable in C++

Impossible to answer without seeing the definition of the type.

Comment: Thanks you for answering :)